# I have an issue to retrieve access_token from code using linkedin api

Tags: linkedin-api

I am trying to integrate LinkedIn login into the website.
I got this issue when I try to retrieve access_token from the code.

I successfully get the code and I got an error response when I retrieve access_token.

This is the code that I used to retrieve access_token.

```
r = requests.post("https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken", 
                        data={'grant_type': 'authorization_code', 'code': code, 'client_id': client_id, 'client_secret': client_secret, 'redirect_uri': 'mydomain/linkedin'})
```

Here is the error response.

```
<html>\n<head>\n  <script type=\"text/javascript\">\n  window.onload = function()\n    {\n      var cookies = document.cookie.split(';'"");\n      for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++)\n      {\n        var fields = cookies[i].split('=');\n        if (fields.length ""== 2)\n        {\n          var name = fields[0].replace(/\\s/g, '');\n          if (name == 'denial-reason-code')\n          {\n    
"       document.getElementById('denialReasonCodes').textContent = fields[1];\n          }\n          if (name == 'denial-client-ip""')\n          {\n            document.getElementById('denialIp').textContent = fields[1];\n          }\n        }\n      }\n      docu""ment.getElementById('denialUrl').textContent = document.location;\n      document.getElementById('denialTime').textContent = (new"" Date()).toString();\n\n     //change to cn domain if it is from cn traffic\n      var isCnDomain = /\\.cn$/.test(location.hostname)"";\n      if (isCnDomain) {\n        document.getElementById(\"helpAnchor\").href = \"https://www.linkedin.cn/help/linkedin/answer/593""2\";\n      }\n    };\n</script>\n  <title>999: request failed</title>\n  <meta http-equiv=\"content-type\" content=\"text/html; charset=""UTF-8\" />\n  <link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"https://static.licdn.com/scds/concat/common/css?h=9z3sq2jihmaimdbx7j4cn""6odq\" />\n</head>\n\n<body class=\"errorpg\">\n\n<div id=\"header\">\n  <a href=\"/home\" ><img src=\"https://static.licdn.com/scds/common/u/""img/logos/logo_linkedin_119x32.png\" width=\"119\" height=\"32\" alt=\"LinkedIn\"/></a>\n</div>\n\n<div id=\"main\" class=\"error404\">\n  <h1>""Request denied</h1>\n  <p>Sorry, we are unable to serve your request at this time due to unusual traffic from your network connec""tion.\n  <br />\n  <br />\n  Please visit our <a id=\"helpAnchor\" href=\"https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/5932\">help pag"
"e</a> and provide the information below for further assistance.</p><br />\n   <b>Reason codes: </b><div id=\"denialReasonCodes\"></div><br />\n   <b>IP: </b><div id=\"denialIp\"></div><br />\n   <b>Url: </b><div id=\"denialUrl\"></div><br />\n   <b>Time: </b><div id":"=\"denialTime\"></div><br />\n  <br />\n\n</div>\n\n</body>\n</html>\n
```

I tried to change the API keys but it didn't work.

Comment: LinkedIn has denied your request due to unusual traffic from your network connection.

Comment: It means my server has been blocked by linkedin?

Answer (score 0):

Next time just `console.log()` the error you receive on the console and provide that in your question, most of the code you pasted in the error response isn't really helpful.

The error is caused by sending too many requests from your IP/Network connection. If you're running things locally, you could try to use a VPN and see if the error goes away.

If you're running the code in a server (i.e: DigitalOcean Droplet) create a new one. Another thing that could work is using a proxy.

Once you've tried all those solutions, if you still encounter the same error, contact LinkedIn's support from the `Resources/Get Support` tab of the [LinkedIn Developers Website](https://www.linkedin.com/developers/apps/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

I use digital ocean for server.
What is the proper solution in this case?
We have to change domain & ip?